# Cakephp-Upload getting image width and height

Tags: cakephp

I'm using `cakephp-upload` plugin by `jose gonzalez` and I can't figure out how do I get the image `width` and `height` so I can store it on the table. How can I do this with this plugin? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these lines in `[UploadBehavior][1]`, in the `beforeSave` function, after line 252.

```
list($imgWidth, $imgHeight) = getimagesize($model->data[$model->alias][$field]['tmp_name']);    
$model->data[$model->alias]['width'] = $imgWidth;
$model->data[$model->alias]['height'] = $imgHeight;
```

This will add `width` and `height` to the model properties. You should have `width` and `height` as columns in the table you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this after `Model::save()` call

```
$image = $this->Event->Image->findById($this->Event->Image->getLastInsertID());

$imageDir = new Folder('img/image');
$imageFile = new File($imageDir->pwd() . DS . $image['Image']['image_dir'] . DS . $image['Image']['image']);
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imageFile->pwd());

$this->Event->Image->id = $image['Image']['id'];
$this->Event->Image->saveField('width', $width);
$this->Event->Image->saveField('height', $height);
```

Comment: you could put it on aftersave http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#aftersave